# How to fix MongoTimeoutException caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to save a dataframe to a mongodb like this:

```
write_format = dataframe.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode(mode)
host = write_format.option("uri", db_host)
database = option_host.option("database", dbs_config.database)
collection = option_database.option("collection", collection)
collection.save()
```

and getting the following error caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=atlas-marketing.fiverrdev.com:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
```

Could you please suggest what to check in order to fix the problem?

Comment: is the Mongo reachable from the Spark node(s)? Because 30 seconds timeout looks suspicious...

Comment: @AlexOtt how to check this?

Comment: I think it's not reachable otherwise it would be able to connect

Comment: easiest way `nc -vz mongo_host mongo_port`

Comment: @AlexOtt  thanks, I think the issue is the client side, not the DB. The instances in dev env are prone to be replacements, because of spot instance. Are there any way to handle this?

Comment: just setup network rules so spot instances will see the DB